# Draw a Circle over a imageview on an Android App

Tags: android, mobile, imageview, android-imageview, android-drawable

I'm doing an map app and I need to draw some circles over a "tapped" area.

I'm able to get the x and y coordinates of the "tap". I already tried to work with canvas, bitmaps and stuff like that, my circles keeps substituting the whole image and don't stay over the tapped spot.

I'm using PhotoView library to manipulate the images (zoom, scroll and etc).

```
@Override
public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {

  //and here should go the code to make the circle 
  //appear over the x y tapped point of the image

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap " + x + " " + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```